# hibernate returning BigDecimal datatype instead of long

Tags: hibernate, long-integer, bigdecimal

The hibernate named query  returns a BigDecimal for a column that has datatype NUMBER.

```
select col1 as "col1" from table1 union select col2 as "col1" from table2
```

On client side, I expect the datatype of col1 to be long (primitive)
I do this:

```
<return-scalar column="col1" type="java.lang.Long" />
```

or

```
<return-scalar column="col1" type="long" />
```

In both cases, I get :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal incompatible with java.lang.Long
```

How can I fix this? My suspiscion, something wrong with the aliasing?

Comment: Are you using Oracle? The Oracle NUMBERtype maps to BigDecimal.

Comment: Yes. Oracle 10g. How to convert to long?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Oracle NUMBER maps to BigDecimal in Hibernate by default.  Try setting the type to BigDecimal.

Comment: Maybe I am not being clear in question. Maybe you are not reading it well. The purpose of <return-scalar column="col1" type="java.lang.Long" /> is to override the default BigDecimal in Hibernate

Comment: @Victor if you need return object really as `Long`  by hibernate, you should change db data type to `LONG`

Answer (score 11):

I don't know what the issue is with your hibernate configuration but as a workaround, one trick that allows you not to care what java `Number` type a Hibernate query returns is to cast the returned value to `Number` and call `.longValue()`:

```
long id = ((Number) em.createNativeQuery("select my_seq.nextVal from dual")
              .getSingleResult())
          .longValue();
```

That way you don't care if the query returns `Long`, `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`, `Short` as long as it fits into a java `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hibernate Maps Oracle Number Type to BigDecimal in Java.
Since BigDecimal computations are costly in Java, once You get the BigDecimal in Java, write a Utility to convert the BigDecimal Collection to Integer or Long collection, based on Your data size.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This fixes the issue neatly and returns a List of Long

```
List<Long> orgTypeIds = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT typeId FROM org_type_cd")
                               .addScalar("typeId", StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
                               .list();
```

ref: https://matthewbusche.com/2016/06/08/hibernate-returning-bigdecimal-instead-of-long/

Answer (score 0):

Since Jpa/Hibernate by default maps the Number datatype to BigDecimal, you can not change this behavior.

You can handle the conversion in the service methods you have.
Convert BigDecimal to int/long based on what the business case needs using `bigDecimal.intValue() or bigDeciml.intValueExact() or bigDecimal.longValue()`