# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have this block of code in OrderService.java

```
    public void deleteOrderByUserId(int userId){
       List<Long> orderIds = orderDAO.getOrderIdByUserId(userId);
       int deleteOrders = orderDAO.deleteOrders(orderIds);
    }
```

This is the code in orderDAO.java

```
public List getOrderIdByUserId(int userId) {
    StringBuilder queryStr = new StringBuilder("select distinct u.OrderId from ");
    queryStr.append("User u where ");
    queryStr.append("u.UserId in (:key)");

    return getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory()
            .getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryStr.toString())
            .setParameter("key", userId).list();
}


    public int deleteOrders(List<Long> orderIds){
      final String deleteOrder = "delete from Order o where o.OrderId in (:orderIds)";
      final Query hibernateQuery = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(deleteOrder);
      hibernateQuery.setParameterList("orderIds", orderIds);
      int count = hibernateQuery.executeUpdate();   
      return count;
     }
```

I'm getting an **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long** Exception while executing this step              **int count = hibernateQuery.executeUpdate();**

What's wrong with that code and how to get rid of that exception

Comment: is `o.OrderId` a `BigDecimal` by chance?

Comment: No. It is of type Long

Comment: What kind of database are you using? If Oracle then maybe that is the cause of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5380867/1506009

Comment: Yeah. I'm Using Oracle. How do I convert it to Long though ?

Comment: What is the [Oracle] data-type of column `OrderId` in database table `Order` ? Is it `NUMBER` ?

Comment: Yes, data-type of column `OrderId` in database table is `NUMBER`

Comment: By default, Oracle JDBC driver maps Oracle database `NUMBER` data-type to java `BigDecimal` class.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of using `hibernateQuery.setParameterList("orderIds", orderIds);`, I've updated it to `hibernateQuery.setBigDecimal("orderIds", orderIds);`

Now it's working fine.

Comment: It may be working fine, but it’s wrong internally. Fine thing you give yourself the _accepted answer_ when you do not comprehend what’s really going on behind the scenes. In fact, I do not even believe that what you say here is right, because your alleged replacement will not compile – at least not with the Hibernate that I have access to.

Answer (score 7):

To get the long value of a BigDecimal object you can call the .longValue() method on it.

Answer (score 1):

`orderDAO.getOrderIdByUserId(userId)` returns a list of `BigDecimal`, not of `Long`, I would guess. It’s hard to tell without the code for that method.

---

EDIT (now that the code is there): Considering https://stackoverflow.com/a/5380867/1506009, you can see that some databases (Oracle comes to mind) return `BigDecimal` (or rather `List<BigDecimal>`) when calling `list()` in Hibernate. Your Java code is faulty in using a raw `List` and just assuming some type when it is indeed another.

`getOrderIdByUserId()` could return `List<? extends Number>`, which would match both `Long` and `BigDecimal`; or it could return `List<BigDecimal>` if that’s the truth. To not use raw types!

`setParameterList()` allows a third parameter, the type of the list elements. Use that.

Comment: added code for `orderDAO.getOrderIdByUserId(userId)`